# node-opcua in connection to OPC UA server 'The user identity token is valid but the server has rejected it'

Tags: node.js, opc-ua, node-opcua

I use the opc client which is on https://github.com/node-opcua/node-opcua.
I have configure the server in anonymous mode but when I want to open a session I get the error: ServiceFault returned by server and
'The user identity token is valid but the server has rejected it' - BadIdentityTokenRejected.

I use this option for connection

```
    {
   securityMode: "NONE",
   securityPolicy: "None",
   requestedSessionTimeout: 10000,
   endpoint_must_exist: false,
   allowAnonymous: true,
   userIdentityTokens: 0,
}
```

would be happy if someone can help me :)